# Effective initialization for sigmoid output layer

Tags: classification, deep-learning

[Glorot & Bengio (2010)](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a.html) show the sigmoid activation function is problematic because it saturates for large inputs and loses much of its non-linearity for small inputs, and suggest using zero-centered activation functions and sampling from a scaled uniform distribution to initialize weights. Sigmoid activations can be avoided in hidden layers, but I don't see any way around using them in the output layer for binary classification. What is an effective way of initializing the weights of a sigmoid output layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper (and recommended initialization) only refers to the hidden layers. They themselves used a softmax (which is a generalized sigmoid) on the final output layer. If you follow their variance derivation you see that they keep the variance w.r.t. the final activation as a fixed term which they don't manipulate:

[image]